# Is there an online javascript test for assignments where conditional expressions are expected?

Tags: javascript, testing, syntax

I've had a look at JSLint but it stops after 2% with a bunch of non-harmful messages, even after asking it to tolerate everything.

For the moment, I'm only interested in finding '=' where '==' or '===' should be, I can move on to the rest later.

If there is no such test, can someone provide me the regex for the following instances:

```
(foo = bar) ? option1 : option2
```

and

```
if (foo = bar) ...
```

Thanks

Comment: How you you use a regular expression there? You are not comparing, you are storing foo into bar. And if you are storing foo into bar in purpose, why are you doing in there and not in its own line where it is easier to read and understand. Inside the if or ternary operator looks like a bug which jslint is yelling at you about.

Comment: What about `var line; while((line = readFile()) == null);`

Comment: `if (foo = bar) ...` is valid. Assignments return "truthy" or "falsy" depending on their values.

Comment: @epascarello I want a regex for searching in the IDE. (foo = bar) is an example of a possibly incorrect assignment. I would search my source code for all similar instances and determine whether they are doing what I intended (ie assigning or comparing).

Comment: @sp00m I've recently written the code so, although pretty large, I know what kinds of statements I've used. The 2 examples I've given are the only two that could be effed up in the particular program I'm looking at.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I know, that's the point. No error occurs so I want to search my source and determine whether such assignments are what I intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), which is a more "merciful" version of JSLint (Crockford was just too strict)

Also, JSLint gets too carried away with formatting errors. You might want to try [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to format the code in a way JSLint sees fit.